# Details on MSCA projects

Tags: projects, marie-curie

Recently I saw an advertisement for a phd position within an MSCA doctoral network. I know the title of the network project  as well as the grant number. Is it possible to get the details of all the individual projects involved with this network?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access the full proposal or grant agreement as they are not public but you may find some information on cordis https://cordis.europa.eu/ though the individual project will probably not be there. Your best option is to google the project name or search euraxess to find the job offers and/or the call documents